# what is the difference between a Riemann integral and Cauchy limit theorem?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-integration

If $f$ is a Riemannian integrable function on $[0,1]$, then $\forall \epsilon >0  \ \  \exists  \delta>0 $ s.t. if the norm of the partitions $||P||< \delta$, then $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1} ^n f(x_k) (x_k - x_{k+1}) -L \right| < \epsilon $ and L is the number $\int_0 ^ 1 f(x) dx$.

Now assume that $f$ is a continuous function, then it is Riemannian integrable and for any sequence $\{ a_n \} $ that converges to 1, $f(a_n) \to f(1)$. Let $\{ b_n \}:=\{f(a_n) \} $,
then by Cauchy limit theorem $\frac{1}{n }\sum\limits_{k=1} ^n b_k \to f(1) $.

If we let the norm $||P|| =\frac{1}{n }$ then why $L \neq f(1)$ by Cauchy limit theorem?

Comment: I don't understand. The theorem about $\sum_k b_k/n\to f(1)$ is rather the *Cesaro* limit theorem, and "$L\neq f(1)$" is meaningless here. I mean, it *does* converge to $f(1)$, so why are you asking why the limit *isn't* $f(1)$?

Comment: Maybe what counts is that you don't know that $a_k-a_{k-1}=1/n$ (does this even make sense?) so $\sum_k b_k/n$ doesn't necessarily come from a Riemann sum

Comment: @FShrike maybe I made a mistake with the name but lets consider a function $f(x)=x^2$
$\int_0^1 f(x)dx =\frac{1}{3} $ however the Cesaro limit  is $1$

Comment: Always in a Riemann sum, partitions have a finite number of elements. You're mixing up a sequence of finite partitions as somehow being one long sequence which converges to $1$. I think. Either way, you haven't convinced me that there really is a Cesaro summation happening here

Comment: @FShrike oh I understand where is the mistake now the sequence $b_n$ is changing in Riemman sum ($b_1$ for example changes every time $||P||$ deceases $

Comment: @FShrike the first time I saw this theorem the first thing that came to my mind is integral  since it has the form of $\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k$

Comment: @Mathematicsenjoyer exactly, in your post $b_k$ is actually $b_k(n)$, i.e. it depends on the choice of the partition $P$.